# JSF error while using datatable

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jsf datatable problem with var attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210987/jsf-datatable-problem-with-var-attribute)

Hello all,

I am doing a JSF application using datatable..Following is the code--

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{dbdata.empno}" var="item" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="4" width="50%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" summary="This is a JSF code to create dataTable." >
```

but I am getting this error.--

```
The method setVar(String) in the type DataTableTag is not applicable for the arguments
```

can you please put some light on it?

Thnak you