# jsf datatable problem with var attribute

Tags: java, jsf

While developing a small jsf application with datatable I am having following problem with this error

```
The method setVar(String) in the type DataTableTag is not applicable for the arguments (JspValueExpression)
```

in my jsp page i have following code fragment

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{dbdata.empno}" var="item" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="4" width="50%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" summary="This is a JSF code to create dataTable." >
```

in my java file i have following 2 code fragments--

```
while (rst.next())
{    
 empno.add(i++,new perInfo(rst.getString(1)));
}
```

---

```
public class perInfo {
    String uname;

    public perInfo(String firstName) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }
}
```

the data is coming fine from database.

I have found that     "var" attribute is giving problem

can you please advise

Comment: hi !can you please elaborate and provide more codes and detail?

Comment: It sounds like a problem of jsf/server versions. Which jsf version and server do you use?

Comment: if i remove var=item then i do not get the error but then no data is displayed also

Comment: Can you format your code and provide us with the error message?

Comment: The method setVar(String) in the type DataTableTag is not applicable for the arguments (JspValueExpression)
 is the error

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199199/jsf-error-while-using-datatable/6199960#6199960). Seems to be a bug with Tomcat 6 and JSF 1.2

Comment: Please do not repost the same question again. You've already posted this before. Whenever you have more detail to add, use the `edit` link below the question. Whenever you can't seem to find your previously asked questions, click the link behind your username in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you ran into this bug:

[Bug 41912 - JSF datatable does not work on tomcat 6.0.9](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41912)

Regarding the comments on this page a possible workaround would be changing the combination of server and/or jsf version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to send a String to a relational database when it's expecting another type, like Date or number, to a particular table and column.

HTTP form elements only know about Strings.  You should be validating and binding values from the UI on the server side before persisting them in a database.

Comment: dbdata.empno is returning an ArrayList .I have     public List getempno() {return empno;} in bean where empno is arraylist.